# Sqlite query is not working

Tags: blackberry

I am using special chracter in sqlite query. its working perfectly on 6.0 simulator or device
but its not working on 5.0 simulator

my query

```
select * from aide where ti = 'ménagères'
```

pls help

Answer (score 0):

This is well known issue of earlier 5.0 OS revisions. They fixed it in some later 5.0 update. My suggestion to your case - use dictionary table with foreign keys (or just replace string constants with some integer). This suggestion isn't valid when you have to store unicode characters to database and there is [workaround](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/UTF8-encoding-and-SQLite-database-problems/m-p/462189/highlight/true#M92232) for it.